# Blockquote an error with < and >

Tags: support, markdown

Often in c# (and possibly other languages) error messages will contain `<` and `>` characters, especially if they use generics.

For example:

---

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func, System.Func, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

---

There are a lot of characters missing in the above text, which markdown removes. Markdown believes it's html, and removes it.

The site's consensus is to put errors in blockquotes. When I do this, markdown will still remove the offending characters.

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func, System.Func, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

I can also make it a code block, but this is tedious and does not look as nice.

```
The type arguments for method 
'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Collections.
Generic.IEnumerable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, 
System.Func<TOuter,TKey>, System.Func<TInner,TKey>, System.Func<TOuter,TInner,
TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments 
explicitly.
```

So, there has to be an easier way to do this. Cupcake blew my mind recently (link gone) by posting an entire answer in blockquotes. I hope there is something just as easy to fix this.

How can I show the full error without markdown removing characters with the least amount of effort on my part (the editor or author)?

<sub>If you really want to know, [this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630559/linq-to-sql-error-on-join) I was trying to edit where I came across this problem</sub>

Comment: I think the code block looks nicer, and I don't see how its any more tedious then blockquotes. At least not with your example. If the text isn't already wrapped you can use back ticks instead of a code block.

Comment: Just a note: mixing blockquotes and code doesn't render the same on the mobile site, since blockquotes are handled differently there. And, FWIW, I agree with Ross. I think code blocks look better, and are easier to visually parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out my edit. To quote,

> To insert the literal character `<` into a blockquote, use &lt; and it will show up as <.

No need to entitize `>` as well, it seems Markdown is smart enough to leave them alone.

Pity there is no easy \escaping them.

Comment: I know that fixes it, but I RREEEEAAALLYYY don't want to do that, but it's easier than code-blocking.

Comment: @gunr2171: then imagine this, I did it using my iPad. No fun at all :-) Behind a *proper* computing device I'd cut the blockquote into a text editor, find/change, copy back. Ten seconds tops, against the painful minutes of arduously attemtping to drag that damn itty bitty little cursor into position ...

Comment: Well, +1 for dedication. But yeah, I was hoping there was some super-easy built in method, but this is a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to choose one or the other, you can mix quote and code formatting.

> The type arguments for method '`System.Linq.Enumerable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Func<TOuter,TKey>, System.Func<TInner,TKey>, System.Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>)`' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.